# How to query data from the WFS Server via the request `GetFeature` using StoredQuery

Tags: wfs, getfeature

I managed it to set up a  WFS `StoredQuery`. The Request `ListStoredQueries` shows my new created query with the id `test` and another StoredQuery that was on the server - i did not build this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:ListStoredQueriesResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:StoredQuery id="urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById">
    <wfs:Title xml:lang="en">Get feature by identifier</wfs:Title>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:sg_gebaeude_f</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:v_sg_flurstueck_l</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:v_sg_flurstueck_t</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:v_sg_gebaeude_t</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:v_sg_lageohnehausnummer_t</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
</wfs:StoredQuery>
<wfs:StoredQuery id="test">
    <wfs:Title xml:lang="en">mein titel:</wfs:Title>
    <wfs:ReturnFeatureType>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f</wfs:ReturnFeatureType>
</wfs:StoredQuery>
```

---

This is the code with which I do this.

```
        <script language="JavaScript">
        console.log("CreateStoredQuery");
        function CreateStoredQuery() {
            var CreateStoredQueryRequest = $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?',
                data: '<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service="WFS" version="2.0.0"'
                    + ' xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0"'
                    + ' xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"'
                    + ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
                    + '<wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id="test">'
                    + '<wfs:Title>mein titel:</wfs:Title>'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xsd:string" />'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fln" type="xsd:integer" />'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fsn_zae" type="xsd:integer" />'
                    + '<wfs:Parameter name="fsn_nen" type="xsd:integer" />'
                    + '<wfs:QueryExpressionText returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" isPrivate="false">'
                    + '<wfs:Query typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" >'

                    + '<Filter>'
                    + '  <And>'
                    + '    <PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:gemarkungsname</ValueReference>${gemarkungsname}</PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '    <PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:fln</ValueReference>${fln}</PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '    <PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:fsn_zae</ValueReference>${fsn_zae}</PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '    <PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:fsn_nen</ValueReference>${fsn_nen}</PropertyIsEqualTo>'
                    + '  </And>'
                    + '</Filter>'

                    + '</wfs:Query>'
                    + '</wfs:QueryExpressionText>'
                    + '</wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>'
                    + '</wfs:CreateStoredQuery>',
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "text",
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " - CreateStoredQuery");
                    console.log(thrownError + " - CreateStoredQuery");
                }
            });
            CreateStoredQueryRequest.done(function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            });

            CreateStoredQueryRequest.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

---

I would like to query data from the WFS Server via the request `GetFeature`.
Here is one of my experiments.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=test&gemarkungsname=Beetz&fln=6&fsn_zae=97&fsn_nen=1
```

---

The result is this error message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression
```

---

What am I doing wrong?